# What are the APIs to get SOA record from a dns query in linux c programming?

Tags: c, linux, dns

I have used dig to see dns query related information but now I need to find some APIs for dns query by which I would be able to get specifically SOA record of my query programatically in C. Last option I can try by reading socket and parsing the format.

But if someone tell me about any function and APIs of c on linux which can provide me to fetch SOA record then that will be great for me. Thanks for the Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to try is the [`res_*`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/res_init) API.  This is part of the Unix C library since 4.3BSD, which means it's very portable (as long as you don't care about Windows) *but* it's also somewhat, er, inconvenient to work with (in particular you have to parse query responses with only minimal library assistance) and doesn't support shiny modern things like DNSSEC.

If you want something a little more polished you're going to have to go for a third party library; I have heard good things about [Unbound](http://unbound.net/) but have never used it myself.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer  .....I am very beginer and i thnk i was looking some thing cooked as i used previusly some ssl libraries etc...On the other hand according to your solution  I tried to get this by first using res_* . where i was having dificulty with even simple implimentation of function APIs.       ATlast I want to ask some example programmes with res_* , that will be really great help for me Thanks again.

Comment: I don't know where to find example res_* code, sorry.  You will probably find Unbound easier to use; 4.3BSD era APIs are often quite beginner-hostile.  [Unbound has a tutorial](https://unbound.net/documentation/libunbound-tutorial-1.html).